# bootrap-vue not accepting url path for image on the carousel

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am creating a website with vue and using bootstrap vue but my image is not rendering.

I am using this

```
<b-carousel-slide
        caption="First slide"
        text="Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum."
        src="../../assets/images/home/DL1.jpg">
</b-carousel-slide>
```

but this does not load the image. But if I use this

```
<img src='../../assets/images/home/DL1.jpg'>
```

Do I need to do anything special to get the url to work?

I also tried using require as this but it did break the page

```
img-src="require('../../assets/images/home/DL1.jpg')"
```

If it helps, I am also getting the image as a 304 Not Modified in my network tab

Comment: did you try `v-bind:src="require('../../assets/images/home/DL1.jpg')"`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I did try this and after making the change, the image no longer rendered to the page at all. I only know this as they way I was doing it before, the image would still load but produce an error in the network tab.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: It was a "304 Not Modified" but, after A ton of tries, I realized that I had not tried restarting my server over the last few hours and looks like this fixed this issue!